# Show burn down charts (or similar info) on the /review page

Tags: feature-request, review

Stack Overflow's [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) page has staggeringly high numbers of "Low Quality Posts" and "Close Votes". This can discourage potential reviewers from contributing, as it can feel like a hopeless task.

It would be helpful if the /review page somehow communicated "yes, these numbers are large, but we are making progress".

Comment: This will look...  *abysmal* on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Really? I've been keeping an eye on "Low Quality Posts" for the past few days, and it seems to go down by a few hundred every day. Slow progress, but still progress.

Comment: Follow-up: Since I posted this question, the number of pending "Low Quality Posts" has dropped from 41.9k to 27k.